# Make a transformed copy of a List using ArrayList constructor

Tags: java, collections

I don't know how you guys call this but is it possible to write something like that? Only these two lines.

```
List<Celsius> listOfCelsiuses = new ArrayList<>();
List<Fahrenheit> listOfFahrenheits = new ArrayList<>(listOfCelsiuses);
```

It basically takes a list of celsiuses and returns a list of fahrenheits. But where should I implement that conversion logic?

Comment: First off, the new implementation should look like, new ArrayList<Celsius>();  But, you can not do that for types that are not the same; you would have to create your own function that would take an ArrayList<Celsius> and return and ArrayList<Fahrenheit>

Comment: Do you have some method which can take instance of `Celsius` and return `Fahrenheit`?

Comment: Is Fahrenheit a parent class for the Celsius class? If so then you need two lines: `List<Fahrenheit> listOfFahrenheits = new ArrayList<>();
       listOfFahrenheits.addAll(listOfCelsiuses);`

Comment: Fahrenheit is not a parent class for the Celsius class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In java 8 this is a candidate for Stream and a [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) call:

```
List<Celsius> celsius;
final List<Fahrenheit> fahrenheit = celsius.stream()
                                           .map(c -> convert(c))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

private static Fahrenheit convert(Celsius c) {
```

Prior to jre 8, you could use Gauva's [Lists.transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) with a [Function](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) that does the conversion.

Comment: It seems that there is no built-in Java SE7 solution. Something like that just needs to override some built-in method. So I accept your answer.